# Loop through Object in PHP

Tags: php, excel, phpexcelreader

I am trying to read each element of an Object array, the code reads values from an excel file and then assign the values to a variable.

```
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {

    $fname = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row);

    echo '<td>' . $fname . '<br></td>';
}
```

The output of 'fname' is  four different names, however I want to read each value using a loop and then assign them to a link as follows:
`www.example.com/fname` so that four different links get opened up when I execute the code. I just can't figure out how to access each element of 'fname' object one by one. I read over examples available online, but to no avail. Please bear in mind I am a newbie to PHP. Thanks

Comment: If `example.com` in a localhosted site we cannot see it

Comment: What does `$row` look like.  Try `var_dump()`.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the link I put here is just as an example, it it not a live url

Comment: Now it is just an example

Comment: @RiggsFolly it was an example to start with. I don't see why I would give out the real website link on a public form

Comment: @AbraCadaver var_dump($row) gave the following output "int(5)"

Comment: I am not suggesting you should. But it was a live clickable link originally, that went nowhere

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok sorry about that. I did so because in the past when I put a link and didn't use html tag , the question got rejected and such.

Comment: What and all are the `keys` you have in $fname ?

Comment: I dont follow what you mean when you say _The output of 'fname' is four different names_ Do you mean each `$fname` actually contains 4 items of data and you want to fiddle with those bits to built an anchor tag?

Comment: I wanted to know whether it's `key-value` pair or just an array of 4 values.

Comment: Show us the results of this line `echo '<td>' . $fname . '<br></td>';` And then show us what you want to be output please

Comment: @RiggsFolly I mean that when I echo $fname it outputs the following: 'Tim John Sam Tom' , so it has 4 elements in it, now if I wanna assign $fname[1] to a variable , or even echo $fname[1] , it results into this error: "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PHPExcel_Cell as array"

Comment: Do you mean you want to `$names = explode(' ', $fname); echo $names[0]; echo $names[1];`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If `$fname` contains a space delimited list of names like `Tim John Sam Tom` then you can use `explode()` to turn that STRING into an array of strings.

```
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {

    $fname = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row);
    $names = explode(' ', $fname);
    foreach ( $names as $name ) {
        echo '<td>' . $name . '</td>';
    }
}
```

So if you use the `$names` array

```
$names[0] would be `Tim`
$names[1] would be `John`
$names[2] would be `Sam`
$names[3] would be `Tom`
```

Comment: ok, but then I how to call each name though? The code you posted just lined up the names as follows: TimJohnSamTom

Comment: Ok what do you mean by _call each name_

Comment: I mean if wanted to do something like: Name1 = Tim where tim, to my understanding comes from$fname[1] atleast logically.

Comment: Arrays are zero based so `$names[0]` would be `Tim`

Comment: And you dont need to create scalar variables, use the array created

Comment: Where do I echo $names[0] ?  I tried the following  '$a = $names[0];
    echo $a;' and the output was still  TimJohnSamTom

Comment: Also, my output for the $fname didn't have any space or comma separated.. it is as follows: TimJohnSamTom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129486/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-dashd).

Comment: Have you dissappeared?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works,

```
    foreach($fname as $values)
    {
        $value1 = $values->keyname1;
        $value2 = $values->keyname2;
        $value3 = $values->keyname3;
        $value4 = $values->keyname4;
    }

    $url = "http://example.com/".$value1;
```

Comment: I did, and nothing happened. Even echoing $value1 didn't output anything

Comment: I have been able to fix it, however when I loop through the link only the very last i.e. $value4 opens up. Could you suggest a way to open all 4 at the same time?

Comment: `only the very last i.e. $value4 opens up` What does it mean ?

Comment: I figured it out !